# How does Mozilla Thunderbird set IMAP flags?

Tags: thunderbird, imap

The IMAP specification supports by default certain flags:

```
\Seen (Seen)
\Flagged (Flagged)
\Answered (Answered)
\Deleted (Deleted)
\Draft (Draft)
\Recent (Recent)
```

I assume that Thunderbird uses the `\Seen, \Deleted`, etc. ones to show which emails have been answered, read, etc. But what about `\Flagged`? Which Thunderbird action corresponds to setting that flag?

From what I see, Thunderbird supports two ways of labeling messages: tags and stars. Tags are covered in http://kb.mozillazine.org/Tags, which says that they are stored using IMAP keywords, so the other way remaining are the "stars" (you can "star" a message as a way to highlight it). Does that correspond to an IMAP flag?

Comment: Which starts ? And the documentation relates mostly to color tags that have no special meaning in IMAP.

Comment: @harrymc Thunderbird has an option to "star" (highlight with a star) certain emails. Does that correspond to the "\Flagged" flag?

Comment: @harrymc In the Mozillazine page I linked, the section "IMAP" says about the color tags "Thunderbird tries to store tags on the server using IMAP keywords", so I guess they *can* be stored  remotely, depending on the IMAP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stars set `\Flagged`, because stars were originally flags before Gmail happened.

The message list of Mozilla 1.7 looked like this:

[image]

(Similarly, Outlook Express also used flags:

[image])